# Map collections without turning them into lists

Tags: generics, collections, clojure

Is it possible to `map` collections without turning them into lists? I know about `mapv` for vectors, but what about sets or maps. Is there a generic `map` function that treats each collection as a functor (i.e. something mappable) and preserves its type after mapping?

Here is what i have mind vs whats happening now:

```
(map inc [1 2 3])         ; => [2 3 4], instead I get: (2 3 4)
(map inc #{1 2 3})        ; => #{3 2 4}, instead I get: (3 2 4)
(map inc {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} ; => {:a 2 :b 3 :c 4}, instead I get: ClassCastException
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The return values from your functions aren't lists exactly, that's simply how they are represented in the REPL when printed. They are really instances of `clojure.lang.LazySeq`, as you can see here:

```
(class (map inc [1 2 3]))
=> clojure.lang.LazySeq
```

Rather than being `mappable`, Clojure attempts to deal with all collections as being `Sequable`. The `Seq` abstraction allows many transformations to be composed together into pipelines of operations on a collection, where maintaining the original input type often doesn't make sense, especially in terms of performance (speed). In this case, the dynamic nature of Clojure is actually quite useful.

It's trivial to convert the output of operations to the collection type that you want:

```
(-> (map inc [1 2 3])
    (vec))
```

or more simply, using `into`:

```
(into [] (map inc [1 2 3]))
```

`into` can be used for lists, maps and sets:

```
(into #{} (map inc #{1 2 3}))
=> #{4 3 2}
```

In your example where you attempt to map over a Hashmap, `map` is passed a sequence of key-value pairs in the form of a `clojure.lang.MapEntry`, so `inc` which expects a number, can't work on it directly.

You could do something like this, using *destructuring* to pull out the keys and values:

```
(into {} (for [[k v] {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}]
           [k (inc v)]))
```

Comment: The `(empty xs)` idiom also preserves metadata and other collection properties (such as sorting function)

Answer (score 0):

`into` function turns any sequence into a specific type. To keep the original type, pass `(empty data)` as the first argument:

```
(def data #{1 2 3})
(into (empty data) (map inc data))
;; #{4 3 2}
```